# Using LIKE with multiple columns in a table

Tags: php, mysql

There are three, possible four columns in the table that I will need to use.

1. year
2. playerName
3. variation

Lets say a user type in 2000 Matt Base. 2000 is the year, Matt is the player name, and base would be variation. However, what if another use types in Matt Base. And another 2000 Matt, or 2000 Base.

I know I can do something like `select * from TBL where name LIKE '%$input%'`

How can I search three columns based on a single user input? maybe explode it at the space and search each section? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to search all three columns in one logical step, as *text*, then I might suggest actually just maintaining a fourth column as such:

```
year | playerName | variation | description
2000 | Matt       | Base      | 2000 Matt Base
```

Now you may search the `description` column based on some user input:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE description REGEXP ?
```

To the `?`, you may bind the search term, surrounded in word boundaries.  For example, to search for `Matt` among the description, bind:

```
"[[:<:]]Matt[[:>:]]"
```

Comment: I guess I can do that, but i also have about 300 entries in the table. would need to figure out a way to combine the current. i like this idea though.

Comment: @soldfor Then see the other answer for the alternative.  You would have to search each column using separate logic.

Comment: i was able to use the concat function and have it do it for me. from there i can use the LIKE. thanks so much for make me use my noggin

Comment: Sure, that should work.  My answer uses a regex search, which you also might want to consider to avoid false substring matches.

Comment: first time doing the regex, but, card REGEXP '[[:<:]]$s[[:>:]]'"; this breaks the code. if i do single quotes around the $s, the api 200s, but the sql is wrong. what am i missing?

Comment: You should be using a PHP prepared statement and then bind e.g. `[[:<:]]Matt[[:>:]]` if you want to search for `Matt`.  I can't explain prepared statements in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OR` Operator in `WHERE` condition for get data from multiple column.
Your query like

```
select * from TBL where name LIKE '%$input%' OR playerName LIKE '%$input%' OR variation 
LIKE '%$input%'
```

You can also set `AND` operator according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the search terms for come in any order, you can do

```
where concat(year, playerName, variation, year, playerName, variation, year) like concat('%',replace(?,' ','%'),'%')
```

Comment: how does the second concat work? the replace(?,' ', '%')? Im guessing the ? is the search term... but from there, you lost me.

Comment: yes, ? is the search term.  I was makiing it so e.g. "2000 Matt Base" does `like "%2000%Matt%Base%"` (adding % to the beginning and end and changes spaces to %)